# Removal of window.onbeforeunload call because it doesn't support in Chrome 80 instead I want to use fetch and sendBeacon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We are using window.onbeforeunload mostly if user does a search for a text within the page in the search box, that is not retained any more. So we want to leverage fetch or sendBeacon for the same for all browsers except IE instead of window.onbeforeunload.

Code Snippet to search text in serach box:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var unloadCatcher = function() {
            var dateObjAjax = new Date();
            var timestamp = dateObjAjax.getTime();
            var sortColumnIndex = $('#example').dataTable().fnSettings().aaSorting[0][0];
            var pageType = "EPPatientList";
            var paginationSize = $("#example_length select option:selected").prop('value');
            var sortDirection = $('#example').dataTable().fnSettings().aaSorting[0][1];
            var searchText = "";
            if ($('#search_input').is(':visible')) {
                searchText = $('#search_input').val();
                $("#hiddenSearchText").val(searchText);
            }
            else {
                $("#hiddenSearchText").val("");
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "<%=userPreference%>&sortColumnIndex=" + sortColumnIndex
                    + "&pageType=" + pageType
                    + "&paginationSize=" + paginationSize
                    + "&sortDirection=" + sortDirection
                    + "&time="+timestamp,
                type: "post",
                data: $("#hiddenSearchForm").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                }
            });

            var otable = $('#example').DataTable();
            var pageSize = otable.page.info().length;

            var expdate = new Date();

            expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 365 * 20));
            $.cookie('SJM_PT_'+userLogonCookieName+'_PageSize',pageSize,{ expires: expdate });
        }

        window.onbeforeunload = unloadCatcher;

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried those alternatives? Are you getting an error with those?

Comment: whatever options are getting online are using navigator.sendBeacon call in window.onbeforeunload event. But I want to remove this. So I am not getting any other alternative to use sendBeacon  and fetch in Chrome 80 instead of window.onbeforeunload